# CiviCRM discount price set active dates storage location?

Tags: events, date, civicrm

This conerns the Civi-created Discount Set of Fees which appears at the bottom of Civi's Event creation page. I have been over the tables and the ERDs and cannot for the life of me discover WHERE the active_on and disable dates reside inside Civi.  I am developing a dedicated front-end interface for a special case, and have to know where these dates are being stored. Within the Civi UI they appear just fine. I simply cannot find their storage location.

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refer to `civicrm_discount` table in CiviCRM database, where `start_date` column 
refers to active and `end_date` as expire date.

When you create Discount Set for an event in CiviCRM, it creates a price set and is linked to "civicrm_discount" via "price_set_id".